# SharePoint Online Track Inactive Users

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-accounts, reports, auditing

How do you setup auditing so that you can track users **not interacting** with SharePoint Online?

Comment: Hi Ricshah, has this post been answered? If so, can you please mark my answer as the answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature is not available with SharePoint Online. 
You might want to look into external tools.